# Pegar valores de uma coluna de um dataframe e criar uma coluna em outro com os valores correspondentes

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho dois dataframes df1 e df2, ambos tem coluna equipe, mas apenas os df2 tem a coluna numeral que todo dia altera, queria que os valores da coluna numeral virassem uma coluna no df1, mas sempre na frente da equipe responsável

exemplo:

```
df1:
equipe
a
b
b
a
c
a
b

df2:
equipe   numeral
a           1
b           2
c           3
```

queria que o df1 ficasse:

```
df1:
equipe    numeral
a            1
b            2
b            2
a            1 
c            3
a            1
b            2
```

Usei esse código, mas ele gera uma coluna inteira vazia

```
def comunidade(num):
    if num == 'a':        
        return def2.loc[index, 'def2']
    elif num == 'b':
        return def2.loc[index, 'def2']
    elif num == 'c':
        return def2.loc[index, 'def2']

df1['numeral'] = df2['numeral'].map(comunidade)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegues fazer isso usando o método `merge`, especificando a coluna onde fazer o `join` (neste caso a `equipe`)

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='equipe', how='left')
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado