# Criar coluna baseada em outro dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Boa noite!
Tenho dois dataframes `ex8_alunos` e `ex8_cursos`

`ex8_alunos`
[image: ex8_alunos]

`ex8_cursos`
[image: ex8_cursos]

Eu gostaria de criar uma coluna no `ex8_alunos` chamada `CO_UF`

Para alimentar essa coluna eu precisaria cruzar os dados dos dois dataframes citados acima
No `ex8_cursos` usar o `CO_IES` e o `CO_UF` para criar no `ex8_alunos` a coluna `CO_UF` e com os respectivos Códigos do UF de cada faculdade.

Eu tentei o seguinte método, sem resultado:

```
ex8_alunos['CO_UF'] = 0
for i in range (0, ex8_alunos.shape[0]):
    if ex8_alunos.at[i, "CO_IES"] == ex8_cursos["CO_IES"]: 
        ex8_alunos['CO_UF'] = ex8_alunos['CO_UF'].append(ex8_cursos["CO_IES"].loc[[i]])
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?
Desde já agradeço!

Comment: pode disponibilizar os dados ou fazer um MWE?

Comment: Estou providenciando!

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Pegar valores de uma coluna de um dataframe e criar uma coluna em outro com os valores correspondentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/435498/pegar-valores-de-uma-coluna-de-um-dataframe-e-criar-uma-coluna-em-outro-com-os-v)

Comment: [ex8_alunos](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16qLPsPlefqi12bJzV6FR0GIRdtMsjNxo/view?usp=sharing)
[ex8_cursos](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vxzdmL5Srjc8WICEOKXBI43O4IHR78ul/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: `ex8_alunos['CO_UF'] = 0`
`ex8_alunos['CO_UF'] = ex8_alunos.merge(ex8_cursos, on='CO_UF', how='left')`
Não deu certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução é fazer o **merge** de forma diferente do que está no comentário

Segue exemplo:

### Criando Dataframes Testes

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 5]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"B": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "C": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]})
```

O conteúdo dos dataframes:

```
>>> df1
   A
0  1
1  2
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  3
6  3
7  2
8  1
9  5

>>> df2
   B  C
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
3  4  d
4  5  e
```

### Fazendo o merge

```
>>> df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on='A', right_on='B')
```

Conteúdo de df3

```
>>> df3
   A  B  C
0  1  1  a
1  1  1  a
2  2  2  b
3  2  2  b
4  2  2  b
5  3  3  c
6  3  3  c
7  3  3  c
8  4  4  d
9  5  5  e
```

Para maiores detalhes veja a [documentação](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html)